# Is the language Turing machine-Input pairs for which the computation loops recognizable?

Tags: turing-machines

I'm wondering if the following language is $L \in \mathsf{R}$, $L \in \mathsf{RE} \setminus \mathsf{R}$, $\overline{L} \in \mathsf{RE} \setminus \mathsf{R}$:
$$L=\{<M,w> \,\mid M \mbox{ Loops on input } w\}$$
to be clear: We say that a TM loops on a string if during its run on the string it repeats the same sequence of configurations. Note that every TM that loops on a string is a TM that doesn’t halt on the string but not every TM that doesn’t halt on a string is a TM that loops on the string.
I'm leaning towards $\overline{L} \in \mathsf{RE} \setminus \mathsf{R}$ and wondering if it's possible to map $\overline{L}$ to HALT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language $L$ is recognizable: you can build a Turing machine that recognizes $L$ by simulating $M$ and keeping track of all the traversed states. As soon as a state is repeated, you accept. If $M$ halts and no stated is repeated, then reject.

Moreover, $L$ is not decidable. Suppose that $L$ was decidable, then you could do the following to solve the halting problem:

- Create a new Turing machine $M'$ behaves as $M$, but instead accepting/rejecting, it goes into some looping state.
- Simulate a Turing machine $T$ that decides $L$ to check whether $\langle M', w \rangle \in L$.
- If $\langle M', w \rangle \not\in L$ then $\langle M, w \rangle$ must not halt.
- If $\langle M', w \rangle \in L$ then either $\langle M, w \rangle$ halts or loops.

  - Simulate $T$ to check whether $\langle M, w \rangle \in L$.
  - If $\langle M, w \rangle \in L$ then $\langle M, w \rangle$ loops, and hence it does not halt.
  - If $\langle M, w \rangle \not\in L$  then $\langle M, w \rangle$ does not loop, therefore it halts.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your idea of a TM that recognizes L̅- why would reject when no state is repeated?  L̅ = M doesn't loop on w

Comment: I'm not sure about which part of my answer you're referring to. In the first part I'm providing a TM that recognizes $L$ (not $\overline{L}$!). In the second part I'm designing a TM that decides the halting problem, under the assumption that $L$ is decidable. Since this is a contradiction, we infer that $L$ cannot be decidable, i.e., at least one of $L$ and $\overline{L}$ is not recognizable. We already know that $L$ is recognizable, therefore $\overline{L}$ must not be recognizable.